# How do you morally justify the requirement that children should support themselves when they reach adulthood?

Tags: ethics

At least in a Western context people widely agree upon the idea that you have to do something voluntarily to be responsible for it. If you sign a contract voluntarily you are bound by it but if someone forces you, at gunpoint, to sign it you are not bound by it. The law and moral generally agree on situations like that.

And it goes even further, most of the time you must have intention to do something to be morally responsible for the consequences of it. If you stumble on a train because it makes a sudden stop and falls on someone who is injured, you are, generally, excused and not convicted for abuse, assault or similar - and most people think this is reasonable.

With all this in mind, how do people justify that children when they turn 18 or something like that no longer can expect their parents to support them?

The parents voluntarily and intentionally (they intentionally had sex, if the child was unplanned it is still a well known fact that having sex can lead to "accidents" and they obviously didn't terminate the pregnancy so in the "normal case" the child "happened" intentionally and voluntarily) had a child. The consequences of that decision is a human being that will need food, clothing, shelter and so on for the rest of her life.

However, by the logic from the first two paragraphs, the child is not responsible for her situation and the consequences of it because she didn't do anything to end up needing all this stuff for the rest of her life.

In fact, we are more generous towards our pets than our children in this respect. We never expect dogs and cats to provide for themselves when they reach a certain age. Instead we realise that getting a cat or dog means that we have to support it with food and shelter for its whole life (yes you can put down an animal but generally doing that to a healthy animal is frowned upon and most people would feel immoral putting down an animal because we don't want it anymore).

Two final remarks:

1. You can't own a human, at least not unless it voluntarily sold itself.
2. Suicide is, IMO, not a reasonable answer. We are biologically programmed to survive (Eat poison and you will throw up. If you are so determined that you can hold your breath until you pass out your autonomic nervous system will save you as soon as you no longer can control your breathing with will power.). It would have been different if our biology were indifferent between life and death.

So how do you morally and ethically motivate that a child must take responsibility for her parents' decision just because she turns 18 (or something like that)? Why aren't parents obliged to support and provide for their child's basic needs for the child's whole life?

Comment: Maybe somewhat in the direction you ask (1st ⅔) https://youtu.be/4YGnPgtWhsw

Comment: Welcome to SE Philosophy! Thanks for your contribution. Please take a quick moment to take the [tour](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/tour) or find [help](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/help). You can perform [searches here](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/search) or seek additional clarification at the [meta site](https://philosophy.meta.stackexchange.com/). Don't forget, when someone has answered your question, you can click on the checkmark to reward the user!

Comment: Motivation is more of a topic for psychology, and this question would be better posted at [SE Psychology](https://psychology.stackexchange.com/) as it is excessively broad and opinion-based. Any ethical analysis by framework for child-rearing would have to be narrowed down a heap.

Comment: As long as they do not commit suicide they keep on living voluntarily. So one is always responsible for their own life to the extent that they are capable, this even applies to cats and dogs in some sense of "responsibility". In any case, grown children aren't cats and dogs in terms of free will and awareness, hence can't be "taken care of" like property. As children grow so does the capability.

Comment: @JD No, I am asking about the **moral motivation**, similar to how you morally motivate sending a criminal to jail (e.g., the criminal has violated someone else's freedom and liberty and therefore, at least temporarily has lost her right to complain about being incarcerated (or something like that)).

Comment: @Conifold But the original decision is still with the parents. And your parents "programmed" you to have a high threshold against committing suicide.

Comment: In that case, "the original decision" is with the genes, or the laws of physics, or, perhaps, God, if he exists. In other words, it is a figment, there is a constant stream of decisions, none of them "original". And that one does not fully determine their current condition, and no one does except maybe God, does not relieve them of responsibility for deciding what is within their capabilities.

Comment: @Conifold I am not talking about any original decision, I am talking about being responsible for the consequences of your decisions, based on free will and being intentional.

Comment: But, for some reason, you assign this responsibility to parents only, as if what happens to children does not depend on their decisions as well.

Comment: Ah, so you have. In that case, moral justification of asking an adult take care of themselves is not about the lack of their choice to be conceived, but that their free will which undergirds their culpability which has grown from conception as non-existent to adulthood as fully formed in adulthood as well as their rights that are concomitant thereto are manifestations of their intentionality which is the fundamental basis for self-determination; where the adult-child is deficient, the parent still is morally encumbered to a degree. The ultimate basis of altruism of biology, after all.

Comment: "*consequences … need … for the rest of her life. … the child is not responsible for her situation*".
It's called "parenting", educating children to one day be responsible for themselves (even if only by longevity).
*Moral* parents are obliged to provide education, preparedness, and a desire to live.
When grown, their children will *want* to be independent, trying for an even better life, no longer held back by you.
"*Immoral*" parents have children to make their *own* lives better.
Typically, but no means always, this is often the difference between having small and large families.

Comment: @RayButterworth That is irrelevant. The question concerns one's responsibility for one's voluntarily and intentional actions. Children could be as independent as they like even if they are supported by their parents. Children don't have a moral duty to, e.g., visit their parents in exchange for being supported by them. That is a one way street.

Comment: This not off topic. See Rousseau , "Du contrat social", on the obligations of parents towards children. The question can be equivalently translated : " How comes the parents do not have a duty to support their children when they reach adulthood?" . The question belongs to " natural law".

Comment: "Children could be as independent as they like even if they are supported by their parents". It depends, too much "support" creates relation of dependence. And why is it a one way street? Most cultures impose a reciprocal moral duty (albeit not as petty as a *quid pro quo*). The problem with your question is that its framework is unclear, you seem to pull moral principles out of a hat without saying what the hat is, most of them idiosyncratic "in a Western context", or any other.

Comment: @Conifold If parents are legally obliged to pay for their children no interdependence will appear. C.f. some retirement scheme - you don't feel grateful to a bank or insurance company when they fulfil what they are obliged to do. That reciprocal moral duty is easy to defend among friends and equals but why should anyone feel a moral duty towards their parents when the relationship was forced upon them in the most unequal way one could imagine. No, I started my questions with the necessary premises: we are only expected to take consequences of voluntarily and intentional actions.

Comment: How does enshrining something into law remove the dependence instead of boosting it? More generally, why *should* anyone feel anything? What is the source of morality here? Is it Christian, utilitarian, Kantian deontology? That is one problem. The other is that your notions of cause and consequence are incoherent, see [fallacy of the single cause](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fallacy_of_the_single_cause).

Comment: @Conifold If something is written in law, the emotional "guilt" or "debt" is probably reduced. At least one can ignore that if one likes to.

Comment: Does one ever truly support oneself in the modern economy?  It seems more accurate to say that one’s dependency shifts from a parent to some other source, such as an employer, a market, a family or an institution.

Comment: @SofieSelnes Yes, it is your physical or mental ability that makes you a wage.

Comment: @d-b, with a few exceptions, one’s ability doesn’t cause money to be created. A wage is a result of transactions - money is exchanged between parties - and even if by convention we hold that work has a standard minimum value, it is still given by human people, companies and public offices, rather than cosmically bestowed.

Comment: @d-b, in the context of the question, isn’t that still a form of dependence? (There is more to say about the social nature of economic value but you seem unwilling to reflect on that)

Comment: @SofieSelnes No, there is no difference between going hunting yourself or being employed in something that is a small link in the modern food supply chain. And no, it is not more to say about freedom of contract, which is what this basically is all about.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question through science, humans have evolved the capacity to have self control as other animals. In particular, we have the largest percentage of prefrontal cortex than any other species - which is the part of the brain that has the ability to control our innate impulses. Hence, **we hold people accountable for their actions to the degree to which they have the capacity to have self control**. Specifically, children do not have a fully developed prefrontal cortex yet until about the age of 25. However, for the purposes of recognition and indoctrination into society, it is generally recognized **the age of 18 is sufficient enough** to become an independent adult. At that point the parents have no moral obligation to support another adult regardless of whether or not that individual is biologically related.

Because responsibility is, at least partially, dictated by necessity, and because the necessity to continue providing has (sufficiently) been rendered void due to the capability of the child now being enough so they can take care of themselves, the parents' responsibility to support and provide for their child's basic needs for the child's whole life is also sufficiently voided/reduced. In other words, there is a difference between necessity to provide and a desire to provide, whereby the necessity is impacted by the (increasing) capabilities of a child to care for themselves.

I think it is noteworthy to mention that there is a difference between Western and Eastern countries such that the latter have more of an emphasis on family values such as caring for one's parents in their old age (and going insofar as having relatively larger families in each household). I believe this has been degrading though.

Following this, there are four ways the age of 18 and continued support can go. 1. The child desires to continue being supported  but not the parents 2. The parents desire to continue supporting the child (and realistically using it as leverage to control the child's life) but the child does not, 3. Both the child and the parents desire for the child to continue being supported, and 4. neither the parents or the child desire for child to continue being supported. This does not account for how often these actually occur. However, at a static level along with how typically decisions such as these require all parties to agree for them to occur, 3/4 of the situations result in the child not being supported.

The reason "desire" is relevant is because of two reasons. One, biologically the general consensus is that humans are fundamentally driven by self interest (and although this is particular debate amongst philosophers and psychologists, that stance will be taken as a perspective through which to answer). Passing one's genes on is good, and is a form of self-interest so they too can pass on their genes on their own. However, this job is not complete until the child is capable of taking care of themselves. This goes into the second reason which is that the child typically does not want to continue being supported because having parents would actually be a hindrance on their life, and in contrast to their self interest. Whether it be the ego and self-righteousness to make their own way  through the world, or to avoid annoyance and control on their life from parents leveraging support on them, or simply supporting their parents when the parents are unable to support the child.

As an example of this, there are a host of [examples in the animal kingdom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parental_care) where parents and their children part ways at a sufficient age. Furthermore, although I touched upon it, I think the idea of autonomy and the philosophical literature surrounding it could be connected and used to answer your question.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/107459/discussion-on-answer-by-holiday-chemistry-how-do-you-morally-justify-the-require).

Comment: I am for some reason blocked from chatting so I can't respond to you there, but yes, I am interested in your response to my last message and the questions in it. Let's continue. I see this as practice to strengthen my argument (or possibly change my mind).

Comment: @hide_in_plain_sight Why do I need an alternative? I don't have nor plan to have any children that will be forced to be members of a state. It is the other way around, people who plan (or already) forced someone to be a member of a state must motivate why that is morally defensible. Besides, I haven't really any opinion about how feasible this is in practice. The important thing for me personally is to act in a way that is morally justifiable. Just because I can steal an unlocked bike in the middle of the night without being caught I don't do it.

Comment: What do you mean with "The relationship here is not the family"?

Comment: @hide, I’m not sure should necessarily does imply can. It is entirely possible that you can be morally obliged to do two logically incompatible things; all that means is that you are also logically condemned to violate your moral code, not that you must now do two logically incompatible things. That is to say, morality might follow a paraconsistent logic, even where metaphysics does not.

Comment: Have we presented an argument to the effect that “surviving to 18” is a guarantee of self-sufficiency? What about parents of severely disabled children? What about young people in comas supported by hospital ventilation that their parents pay for?

Comment: @SofieSelnes Very unfortunate that you didn't received any feedback on your last two comments. Guess we can conclude that we are "right" and that most people never have reasoned about these questions.